# Issue with DialogflowCX where My voiceBOt is not able to capture Medra Keywords in Long Utterances and respond as Bien in the Next Intent

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Our Voice Bot which is in Spanish is Configured in Dialog flowCX and Integrated to the Voxim plant. We have a list of Medra Keywords like "Absceso subperióstico" ,"Absceso tuberculoso del sistema nervioso central". We are facing an issue where the bot is not able to recognize Medra Keywords in Long Utterances and Respond as "Bien".

We have mapped the list of Medra Keywords to Routes and Tried Testing But it did not work. We tried even adding all the media keywords to Entity types, Trained the BOt, and Tested even Then It did not work